# Как правильно реализовать отправку $_POST данных и возвращение ошибки?

Tags: php, ооп, mvc

В общем, есть маленькая mvc, пишу на ней.
Сейчас пишу регистрацию, и возникло "размышление":
Метод register принимает введенные данные с инпута - что мне дальше делать? Ну, т.е - проверить на корректность веденных данных и пустоту, и если все норм - передаю данные в метод(модель) reg и там уже делаю все что нужно(добавление в бд) или же, лучше передавать веденные данные в модель(сразу) и там уже проверять, если ошибка - возвращаю return false и проверяю if(!Auth::reg($_POST['login'].....) $this->error('Не верно введены данные') ?
И еще, как лучше будет делать условие if($_POST['submit']) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function actionRegister(){
    $model = new Auth();

    if($model->load($_POST['form']) && $model->validate() && $model->save()){
       //redirect
    }

    $this->render('register', [
        'model'=>$model
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Забыли:
if($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post) && $model->validate)).
А если по существу:
Хорошо, в контроллере создаю новый объект 
С чего Вы взяли, что у меня в модели существует метод "лоад"?
Насчет проверки - понял, спасибо. Но тем не менее, код для фрейморвка(грубо говоря).
А у меня "маленькая" самописная mvc, и учитывая ваш пример - мне требуется переписать логику, создать главный класс модели, и внедрить туда все данные методы.Спасибо.

Comment: Но вообще - Вы однозначно правы.
Просто, у меня это мой первый опыт(Yii не в счет)), и я не уверен, что смогу такое реализовать.
Но попробую, очень интересно, так как в дальнейшем планирую что-то писать на этой mvc(если доведу до ума).
Что-то подскажете насчет контроллера?(Т.е, как должны быть методы в базовом(от которого все будут наследоваться)).
Спасибо.

Comment: Я не знаю о возможностях вашей маленькой MVC, но если уже начали её писать сами, тогда логично делать это правильно изначально. Ибо человек работающий после вас с ней, будет вспоминать "добрым" словом автора)) Я видел мало достойных самописных MVC. Сам разрабатываю сейчас один, но лишь потому что проект legacy и перевести пошагово на Yii2 его на данный момент просто невозможно. Рекомендую группировать поля формы, дабы они не размазывались в $_POST. Возможно вам понадобится в будущем отправлять сразу две формы для разных моделей, разруливать поля руками для каждой, не айс в отличии от load

Comment: По контроллеру добавьте обёртку над action. Чтоб был хотя бы beforeAction

Comment: не совсем понял насчет контроллера если честно.
Обертку экшена?
beforeAction?
Насчет модели - да, сейчас "помучаюсь" и попытаюсь реализовать данные методы(в любом случае, в дальнейшем апдейты делать нужно будет, на пару апдейтов меньше, и легче будет)).

Comment: Когда определяете роутингом на какой экшен прыгнуть, добавьте событие beforeAction, в котором в дальнейшем сможете проверять Access к экшену и прочую логику